# ATIX550 Can‘t use HardwareShadowMap in Cg?

Tags: shader, cg

sorry about my English. I am not good at English.
Exactly the same code,in the GF7600GT, Tex2Dproj can return the correct value. But the X550 return to the depth of texture samples, ATI graphics card is not fully support the NV of Cg?

Answer (score 1):

Older ATI cards (or is it just old drivers?) do not support PCF, which is what tex2Dproj is doing so you will have to do it yourself. You will probably have to use fetch4 and you can see a discussion on how to use it [here](http://www.devmaster.net/forums/showthread.php?t=11100)